# Trim actions for all properties

Tags: c#, trim

I have a typical website with admin part where admin can add many different entities. I, as developer, have to trim each of them (to prevent enter entities like '         status name      '. I do it i.e. in Validate method IValidatableObject interface:

```
   public class AddProjectViewModel : ProjectFormBaseViewModel, IValidatableObject
    {
        public int? ParentProjectID { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            ProjectName = ProjectName.Trim();
            DescriptionText = DescriptionText.Trim();
```

Of course, I can do it in method where project is adding to DB or anything else.
But if I have 10 forms and each form has 2-3 string properties, then this code is a little "straight". Maybe anybody can recommend other, more "beautiful" approach to trim all string parameters? I.e. via attribute of property or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you use reflection?

```
var obj = YourObjectToBeTrimmed();
foreach(var property in obj.GetType().GetProperties().Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(string))) {
    property.SetValue(obj, (property.GetValue(obj) as string).Trim());
}
```

Also one can use attributes or other modifications of the reflection.

**EDIT**. Now I modify my answer due to OP's request. In the following code all properties marked by TrimAttribute will be trimmed.

```
class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            // The sample properties.
            var notTrimmedString = "  smth   ";
            var trimmedString = notTrimmedString.Trim();

            // Prepare an object to trim its properties.
            var obj = new A {
                PropertyToBeTrimmed = notTrimmedString,
                PropertyNotToBeTrimmed = notTrimmedString,
            };

            // Trim properties marked by TrimAttribute.
            foreach(var property in obj.GetType().GetProperties().Where(x => 
                x.PropertyType == typeof(string) &&
                x.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TrimAttribute), true).Any())) {
                property.SetValue(obj, (property.GetValue(obj) as string).Trim());
            }

            // Check.
            Console.WriteLine(obj.PropertyToBeTrimmed == notTrimmedString);
            Console.WriteLine(obj.PropertyNotToBeTrimmed == notTrimmedString);
            Console.WriteLine(obj.PropertyToBeTrimmed == trimmedString);
            Console.WriteLine(obj.PropertyNotToBeTrimmed == trimmedString);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sample class.
    /// </summary>
    class A {
        /// <summary>
        /// This property must be marked by TrimAttribute. 
        /// So it will be trimmed.
        /// </summary>
        [Trim]
        public string PropertyToBeTrimmed { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// This property must be not marked by TrimAttribute. 
        /// So it will not be trimmed.
        /// </summary>
        public string PropertyNotToBeTrimmed { get; set; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Custom attribute which means need for trimming.
    /// </summary>
    class TrimAttribute : Attribute { }
```

I suppose [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) tutorial will help you if you are new to reflection and attributes.

Comment: But if I want to trim all except one? :) Need to have another approach... maybe attribute will be better...

Comment: @OlegSh I have updated my answer. See explanation and comments in code.

Answer (score 0):

Can you trim the properties in the ViewModel itself?

```
public class MyModel
{
    private string _prop;

    public string Prop
    {
        get
        {
            return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_prop) ? _prop.Trim() : this._prop;
        }
        set
        {
            this._prop = value.Trim();
        }
    }
}
```